# Prove that if $t_n$ is a perfect square, so is $t_{4n(n+1)}$

Tags: number-theory

Prove that if $t_n$ is a perfect square, then $t_{4n(n+1)}$ is also one. Note that $t_i$ is the $i$th triangular number.

Since $t_n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} \implies t_{4n(n+1)} = t_{4(2t_n)} = t_{8t_n} = t_{8k^2} = \frac{(8k^2)(8k^2 + 1)}{2} = (4k^2)(8k^2 + 1)$

Clearly, $4k^2(8k^2 + 1)$ is not necessarily a perfect square (consider $k=2$). Is there a mistake in the proof or is there a different approach?

Comment: What does "$\in x^2/x \in \mathbb{Z^{+}}$" mean? What is $x$ for that matter?

Comment: That means that it's a perfect square. A rigorous definition.

Comment: As far as I know , $\;x^2/x=x\;$ ...

Comment: So $\,t_n\in x^2/x\,$ is *your* way of saying that $\,t_n\,$ is a perfect square integer? That's odd...

Comment: That is just a way of saying the set of all $x^2$s such that each $x$ belongs to the set of positive integers. Anyway, I edited the question.

Comment: @AnanayAgarwal, I'm afraid your last comment doesn't make any sense...or perhaps it's only me not understanding it at all.

Comment: @AnanayAgarwal: Using standard notation, the correct method of saying that would be
$$t_n\in\{x^2\mid x\in\mathbb{Z}^+\}.$$
See the [Wikipedia article on set-builder notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation).

Comment: Well, I seem to have misunderstood the "such that" symbol.

Comment: You know, the $k^2$ in $8k^2 + 1$ cannot be any arbitrary square, it has a special structure.

Comment: Not only that, @AnanayAgarwal" you also missed the very-important curly parentheses which make a world of difference.

Comment: @AnanayAgarwal, $8k^2+1=8\cdot\frac{n(n+1)}2+1=4n^2+4n+1=(2n+1)^2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $$t_n=\frac{n(n+1)}2=a^2$$

$$t_{4n(n+1)}=\frac{4n(n+1)\{4n(n+1)+1\}}2=4\cdot \frac{n(n+1)}2\cdot(4n^2+4n+1)=4a^2(2n+1)^2=\{2a(2n+1)\}^2$$